# Mesh deforms on final render

Tags: rendering, camera

The object size changes when rendering. The whole object shrinks vertically. I haven't used  Subsurf Modifier. But I did realize that in Render Preview the object size is normal. As soon as I render the image, it is shrinked.

[image: Render Preview]

[image: Rendered - Final]

Blender File: [.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sdHQ1Vz2yYqKxM1IGLMSmzpVwL8T8f7E/view?usp=sharing)

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: 1. In your Render Settings > 'Dimensions', set your pixels to square: (Aspect ratio, both X and Y to 1). 2. In Render Settings > 'Post Processing', uncheck 'Fields'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render settings you have your aspect ratio set to something other than 1 and 1 for the X and Y values. This will scale the image while rendering and give you the result you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you Brenticus. I did the Reset to default settings for the Aspect Ratio and it is how it's supposed to be now.